# Error in lex chatbot - Intent jokeintent is fulfilled

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, chatbot, amazon-lex

I have researched this error for hours and have also tried many different edits and nothing seems to give me a different response in the chatbot. I keep getting "Intent jokeintent is fulfilled" in the chatbot instead of the joke I am wanting. Seems like this has to do with the response the chabot is getting from the lambda function. I can't seem to get it right. Can anyone help?

-testing the lambda function gives me the correct joke
-Lex 2 is being used
-I do have the fulfillment lambdad ode hook selected
-I do have the settings on the chatbot selecting the lambda function

Lambda Function:

```
import json
import boto3
import os

def dad_joke():
    return "How do you find Will Smith in a snow storm? Find the fresh prints"

def random_joke():
    return "Why was Cinderella so bad at soccer? she kept rnning away from the ball"
    
def animal_joke():
    return "What do rabbits eat for breakfast? IHOP"

def poop_joke():
    return "What did one piece of toilet paper say to the other? I'm feeling really wiped"
    
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # telling Lex what to do with response
    response = {
        "sessionState": {
            "dialogAction": {
                "type": "Close"
            },
            "intent": {  
                "name" : "jokesIntent",
                "state": "Fulfilled"
            }
        },
        "sessionId": "test_session",
        "messages": {   
            "contentType": "PlainText"
        }
        
    }

    print(event)
    if event["sessionState"]["intent"]["slots"]["joketype"] == "random joke":
        response["messages"]["content"] = random_joke()
    else:
        if event["sessionState"]["intent"]["slots"]["joketype"] == "animal joke":
            response["messages"]["content"] = animal_joke()
        else:
            if event["sessionState"]["intent"]["slots"]["joketype"] == "dad joke":
                response["messages"]["content"] = dad_joke()
            else:
                if event["sessionState"]["intent"]["slots"]["joketype"] == "poop joke":
                    response["messages"]["content"] = poop_joke()
    return response
```

Answer (score 0):

{
action: "lambda:InvokeFunction",
principal: new iam.AnyPrincipal(),
}
Add this permission to your lambda
If it works, you can limit your principal later on